# Java "not removing" queue

Tags: java, queue

Is there in Java any class that provides the same functionalities as Queue but there's option that returns object and DO NOT remove it just set it at the end of collection?

Comment: You mean like the `peek` method in the `Queue` interface?

Comment: No. As we know peek returns the object BUT the object is still at the top. I want to get object and place the object at the end of the "queue"

Comment: im not completely sure about the question but couldn't you take it out of the queue and put it back in after assigning it to a variable?

Comment: In that case, no such thing comes with Java.

Comment: You May implement queue interface and override the method logic as per your needs.

Comment: Do you want other queue-like methods, or just that circular aspect? Because if all you want is the circular aspect, you don't even need a queue. Just maintain a List and an `int idx`. On each get, just do `list.get(idx++)`, and if the incremented idx is past `list.size()`, reset it back to 0.

Comment: @IksSki As you see many users are a bit confused about what you want to achieve. Next time you should state more clearly what you want. For example by giving a small example with an input and desired output :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Queue` does not directly provide such a method. However you can easily create this functionality with `poll` and `add`, i.e. **removing** (and getting) the **first element** in the queue and afterwards **re-adding** it **to the end** of the queue.

---

This approach has **no disadvantages** compared to other implementations of the same functionality. Note that both operations can be executed in `O(1)` for most implementations, like `LinkedList` for example. The `PriorityQueue` however is slower at insert `O(log(n))` but you **can't avoid that**.

Also note that even if you would design your own `LinkedList` or `PriorityQueue`, you would end up using the same logic for this operation: remove the first element and re-append it at the end.

---

Here is some code:

```
public <E> E pollAndReInsert(final Queue<E> queue) {
    final E element = queue.poll();
    queue.add(element);
    return element;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Queue interface itself provides the `peek();` and `element();` functions that return but do not remove an element.

Comment: I know, but that functions do not place object at the end of collection after use

Comment: then just add it back in after removing the element.